# Running selenium tests on Virtual box guest

Tags: eclipse, windows, internet-explorer, selenium, virtualbox

So i am trying to run Selenium tests written in Java through Eclipse on my guest machine.

My host machine is Windows 7 and I am running Windows 7 guest machine. I have set 2 network adapter NAT and Host only. I am farily new to the whole Selenium testing so I am still exploring all the stuff.

I already run hub and node on my guest with next commands:

```
java -jar selenium-2.39/selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role hub -port 4444 -host 192.168.56.1
```

and node with:

```
java -jar selenium-2.39/selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role node -port 5555 -hub http://10.0.2.15:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=internet explorer,version=11,platform=WINDOWS" -host 192.168.56.1
```

from Eclipse i am trying to access hub on **http://192.168.56.1:5555/wd/hub** and **http://192.168.56.1:4444/wd/hub** but in both cases i get an error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35'
System info: host: 'xxxxx', ip: '192.168.xxx.xxx', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
...
```

I do not know if I am using the correct IP addresses in both cases, if i go into my browser on guest machine i can access the console from hub

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.

So after long playing with the setting I finaly made this working. First thing is I disabled the Host-Only networking and left only NAT and I've set up a port 4444 forwarding from my host (127.0.0.1) to guest (10.0.2.15).

I've run hub with

```
java -jar selenium-2.39/selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role hub
```

And node with

```
java -jar selenium-2.39/selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role node -port 5555 -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=iexplorer,version=11,platform=WINDOWS" -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=selenium-2.39/IEDriverServer.exe
```

Later on in Eclipse under **Debug Configurations** under **Environment** tab i set new property (notice: it is custom property in this case)

**xx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.selenium.properties.remoteUrl** with value **http://localhost:4444/wd/hub**

After running tests I could reach my remote hub.